# Read a file line by line

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read a file line by line, but I don't know how to stop when I reach the EOF.

I have this code:

```
readWholeFile = do inputFile <- openFile "example.txt" ReadMode
                readALine inputFile

readALine x = do y <- hGetLine x
                 print y
                 readALine x
```

and it obviously always terminata raising an exception.

How can I solve?

Edit: exact error message is:

```
*** Exception: example.txt: hGetLine: end of file
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is, hIsEOF

Check out http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html

Answer (score 20):

One more solution. You can lazy read file with `readFile`, lazy split it on-demand and take result line by line:

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines = fmap lines . readFile
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`hIsEOF`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v:hIsEOF) to check the EOF status manually before reading a line, or you can just use the readily available (lazy) [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:readFile) function.

Answer (score 4):

You can test the handle x with `hIsEOF` before reading further. hGetLine fails when the end of file is encountered when reading the first character of the line